# Meteor Publication and Subscription order in React

Tags: mongodb, meteor, reactjs, meteor-react

I'm trying to write a React component which subscribes to data on the server by passing the collection name as a prop. (in the example the name is still hardcoded to keep things simple) Since the collection names can change dynamically, I'm calling a method to construct the publication and server collection variable. Now the theory is to construct the data publication, server and client mongo collection variable in a parent component and the subscribe to this publication in the child component. The parent component is set up like this:

```
    export default class TilesSingle extends TrackerReact(Component) {
      newDataCollection(){
        Meteor.call("setupData","randomcollectionname");
        if(!window["randomcollectionname"]){
          window["randomcollectionname"] = new Meteor.Collection("randomcollectionname");
        }
      }
      render(){
        this.newDataCollection();
        return(
          <div>
            <DataObject />
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

The setupData method looks like this:

```
Meteor.methods({
    setupData(collectionname){
      if(!global[collectionname]){
        global[collectionname] = new Meteor.Collection(collectionname);
        Meteor.publish("pub."+ collectionname,function() {
          return global[collectionname].find();
        });
      }
    }
})
```

And the child DataObject component looks like this:

```
    export default class DataObject extends TrackerReact(Component) {
      constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
          subscription: {
            tiledata: Meteor.subscribe("pub.randomcollectionname"),
          }
        }
      }
      componentWillUnmount(){
        this.state.subscription.tiledata.stop();
      }
      findData(){
        post = window['randomcollectionname'].findOne();
        console.log(post)
        return post;
      }
      render(){
        obj = this.findData();
        if(!obj){
          obj = {};
          obj["score"] = 0;
        }
        return(
          <div>
            <h4>{obj.score}</h4>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Notice that I'm logging post in the findData() function. When I refresh, the console logs:

```
undefined
undefined
> Object {..}
> Object {..}
undefined
undefined
```

It is almost as if the subscription works and then stops working. I'm thinking that it has to do with the order in which react renders these components, and that the method is not finished on the server by the time the client tries to render the child component. Any Ideas?